# Retrieving profile image from Google+ API

Tags: google-plus

I am trying to pull JSON data from Google+ API.  When I include the image attribute size of the image is set to 50px.  How do I change the image size? I don't see it on the docs.

GET [https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/100300281975626912157?fields=image&key={YOUR_API_KEY}](https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/100300281975626912157?fields=image&key=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D)

Response

```
{
 "image": {
  "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-U353P5vNuRE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABKM/a7U7bq251x0/photo.jpg?sz=50"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

At the end of your URL string there's a attribute called sz=50

I just tried to change the attribute, and as result the image's size is changed aswell.

Try these two urls:

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-U353P5vNuRE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABKM/a7U7bq251x0/photo.jpg?sz=50

and

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-U353P5vNuRE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABKM/a7U7bq251x0/photo.jpg?sz=150

See the difference?

Comment: I see that.  But I would like to do that in this HTTP request https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/100300281975626912157?fields=image&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Comment: @Maca there is no parameter to specify the size directly in the request yet, so for now changing the image url afterwards is the only way to get a different size.

Answer (score 11):

There are two kinds of google images:

1. User-uploaded profile Image (ending with s96-c)

- For User-uploaded Image end of URL will contain "s96-c"
  just replace that with "s{anyhighernumber}-c"
  Example: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GicX6CDo0rdCvI0him0hiURm8RFk6aStpHOZQUu=s1500-c

2. Google generated image (ending with photo.jpg)

- For Google Generated Image add "?sz={anyhighernumber}"
  at the end of the URL
  Example:
  https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-smcmFKIr8Mw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AMZuuclFvz6ooU0vUDd-Qkpk5ExSRyEoFg/s96-c/photo.jpg?sz=1500

replace {anyhighernumber} with your desired resolution eg:1500

Answer (score 5):

Just have to change the sz suffix indicating the wnated size, here is the suffix:

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-U353P5vNuRE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABKM/a7U7bq251x0/photo.jpg?**sz=150**

If you cut the param, you would get the default photo sized

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-U353P5vNuRE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABKM/a7U7bq251x0/photo.jpg

And an automatic change in the string:
https://jsfiddle.net/upyL4onm/3/

```
var newSize="300"
var str = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-U353P5vNuRE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABKM/a7U7bq251x0/photo.jpg?sz=50";
var res = str.split("?sz=50")[0]+"?sz="+newSize;
```

And the console.log(res) will output:

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-U353P5vNuRE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABKM/a7U7bq251x0/photo.jpg?sz=300

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me:

```
let profilePicture

if (userObject.picture.includes('s96-c')) {

  profilePicture = userObject.picture.replace('s96-c', 's300-c')

} else if (userObject.picture.includes('?sz=')) {

  profilePicture = userObject.picture.substring(0, userObject.picture.indexOf('?')) + '?sz=300'

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no way in the api to do this, you can just use `sustr` to remove the `?str=` and add your own:

```
$imageUrl = substr($user['image']['url'],0,strpos($user['image']['url']."?sz=","?sz=")) . '?sz=100';
```

Or for javascript:

```
iamgeUrl=user[image][url].substr(0,user[image][url].indexOf('?str=')) + '?sz=100';
```