# Login with google get large profile picture

Tags: javascript, google-signin

i am using this code to implement login with google in my website.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>

<script>
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
  console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
}
</script>
```

but i am getting small profile pic in console. how can i get url for largest profile pic from google?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the query parameters to the imageurl ?sz=x, where x is your image size.

Basically answered here

[Retrieving profile image from Google+ API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020985/retrieving-profile-image-from-google-api)

Comment: its working but i think the resolution is not increasing with size.

Comment: That's because google api doesn't give you the big image :(

Comment: any solution to get the big image?

Comment: You would somehow have to resolve googles image location :S

Comment: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/ check out this

Comment: This is great solution! Thanks!